# Error 'bad pad value "2m": must be positive screen distance' when using tk_messageBox on a wayland display (CentOS)

Tags: centos, tcl, tk-toolkit, wayland

My Tcl scripts run fine on Ubuntu, but now I have copied one to CentOS Linux 8 and get the error mentioned above.

Even when I just start wish and enter a tk_messageBox command, the error appears.

The installed version is tk.x86_64 1:8.6.8-1.el8

Is there any way to get around this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Wayland, you'll have to set the `tk scaling` manually.
I have code like this to set a default:

```
  # fedora 25 has a bug where 'Inf' is returned
  # but once set is ok...
  set tkscale [tk scaling]
  if { $tkscale eq "Inf" } {
    tk scaling -displayof . 1.3333
    set tkscale 1.3333
  }
```

My comment is incorrect, it should say Tcl returns "Inf" when the
screen size is 0.

I found the ticket I opened:
https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview?name=2524085333

Comment: Wayland actually returns 0 for the screen width and Tcl divides by 0 and returns "Inf".   I complained, but the Tcl crowd seems to think that "Inf" is a number.

Comment: File a bug with Wayland for producing lies.

Comment: Inf _is_ a number. Many programming languages understand this. Even in IEEE numbers the values +/-Inf are included.