# tkinter messagebox - bad pad value "2m"

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tkinter, debian, tk-toolkit

I am trying to make `tkinter.messageBox` to work. Here is the minimal code required to reproduce the error:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def call_handler():
    messagebox.showerror("Title", "message")


w = tk.Tk()
w.geometry("200x200")
frame = tk.Frame(w)
btn = tk.Button(frame, command=call_handler, text="Click me!")
btn.pack()
frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
w.mainloop()
```

Here is what I get after clicking the `btn`:

[image: tkinter messageBox]

The messageBox is that thin strip in the middle of the window. When I resize it, it is completely empty.

[image: tkinter messageBox resized]

In my terminal I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "test.py", line 6, in call_handler
    messagebox.showerror("Title", "message")
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/tkinter/messagebox.py", line 94, in showerror
    return _show(title, message, ERROR, OK, **options)
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/tkinter/messagebox.py", line 72, in _show
    res = Message(**options).show()
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/tkinter/commondialog.py", line 44, in show
    s = w.tk.call(self.command, *w._options(self.options))
_tkinter.TclError: bad pad value "2m": must be positive screen distance
```

I will be grateful for any hints on how to further fix that issue. I found the similar issue([Error 'bad pad value “2m”: must be positive screen distance' when using tk_messageBox on a wayland display (CentOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027429/error-bad-pad-value-2m-must-be-positive-screen-distance-when-using-tk-messa) but not really sure how to apply that in python3 tkinter.

Comment: From the link that you posted, it looks like the problem is OS/Tcl version dependant. What OS/Python/Tcl version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using Python 3.8, tcl8.6, Debian 10.